# Selenium chrome use multiple add_experimental_option

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-options

I want to use 2 experimental options on my selenium chromedriver project, but I don't get enough information about the "add_experimental_option" function, I want to use 2 experimental options "prefs" and "debuggerAddress", and when I try to run it, it gets error, I can only use one of them, how can I use both of them?

```
opt = Options()
opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222")
opt.add_experimental_option("prefs", { \
    "profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2
})
```

error messages

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exampleselenium.py", line 28, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe",options=opt,service_log_path='NUL')
  File "C:\Users\Faraaz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Faraaz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\Faraaz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\Faraaz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Faraaz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: cannot parse capability: goog:chromeOptions
from invalid argument: unrecognized chrome option: prefs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [ChromeOptions objects](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities)

- *prefs [type: dictionary]*: A dictionary with each entry consisting of the name of the preference and its value. These preferences are only applied to the user profile in use.
- *debuggerAddress [type: string]*: An address of a Chrome debugger server to connect to, in the form of <hostname/ip:port>, e.g. '127.0.0.1:38947'

You can add both the `experimental_option` as follows:

```
opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images" : 2}
opt.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe', options=opt, service_log_path='NUL')
```

Comment: it does not work for me, I still get the error when I use the experimental option twice