# How to Enable 'Developer Mode' in Chrome Extension screen in Selenium automation

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver

In my selenium+python automation, I have to install an extension before I actually start website automation. But, In my corporate network, I can upload the extensions to Chrome browser only when I unpacked the .crx file. This is my company policy.
When I run the automation script, every time a fresh browser instance launches and 'Developer Mode' in extensions screen is disabled. I need to enable the developer mode from code. I have tried with below arguments in Chrome options but none of them worked.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("--force-dev-mode-highlighting") 
options.add_argument("--system-developer-mode")
```

Any help to make it work will be highly appreciated.

Comment: [Running Selenium WebDriver using Python with extensions (.crx files)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24182729) ?

Comment: This does not work as I am in corporate network, and installing .crx is disabled. The only way I can add extension is uploading unpacked .crx file. But, as I mentioned in the question, 'Developer Mode' is disabled and 'Upload Unpacked' option is not available. So I need Developer Mode enabled before actually the browser launched.

Comment: Change the prefs to `{"extensions.ui.developer_mode": true}`, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64960630).

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you. It is not working. Is there any other way?

Comment: Use `--load-extension=` + path-to-unpacked-directory in add_argument.

Comment: I am already using it. Since there is no 'Developer Mode' toggle enabled, it is not working.

Comment: If the toggle can't be enabled it can only happen if it's disabled by policy, you can see it by opening `chrome://policy`, in which case there's no way to enable dev mode.

Answer (score 0):

From last comment from @wOxxOm, that worked for me: Change the prefs to `{"extensions.ui.developer_mode": true}`, example.

```
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs',{"extensions.ui.developer_mode": True,})
```

Thank you @wOxxOm